# How to align contents of <p:panel> vertical-align to center

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

In my JSF-PrimeFaces webapp I am having  and I need to vertical-align its contents to center. How can I do that?

```
<p:panel id="businesses_panel" header="#{business.businessName}" styleClass="mini-panel panel-grid tr panel-grid td panel-hover panel-header-title-small">
<div align="center">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
        <h:graphicImage alt="#{business.businessName}" value="#{business.logoFullPath}" class="small-panel-image" />
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<p:panel style="height:500px;position:relative;"/>
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="centered">
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
        <h:graphicImage alt="#{business.businessName}" value="#{business.logoFullPath}"    class="small-panel-image" />
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

`height` value is randomly given it does not matter, but do not erase `position:relative`.

```
.centered {
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin:auto;
}
```

For horizontal you should add below rules:

```
left:50%;margin-left:-100px;width:200px;
```

Look out, `margin-left` value is the -1/2 times of `width` value.

**Result:**

[image]

If `width` is not fixed you can try this way it works on me and aligns it center horizontally and vertically at same time:

```
<p:panel style="line-height:200px;padding: 5% 0;position: relative;"/>
    <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="centered">
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
        <h:graphicImage style="vertical-align:middle;" alt="#{business.businessName}" value="#{business.logoFullPath}"    class="small-panel-image" />
        <div class="component-spacing-top"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:panel>
```

Note that graphicImage has `style` property as well.

```
.centered {
position:relative;
height: 100px;
margin:0 auto;
padding: 10% 0;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Even if doesn't work you should check the link that I gave inside `about`. That was what I am doing there are 6 ways and you should mix them.

- [About](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)
- [Demo](http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre4.html)

Comment: @Abhishek It should, anyway could check it out again with this way?

Comment: Yes this way vertical align works but list horizontal alignment.

Comment: @Abhishek question was about vertical that's why I didn't listed. But now you can align your content horizontal as well.

Comment: Width is not fixed in my case, infact I am having this entire component inside a datatable. So width depends on the contents. Is there a solution for this and thanks a ton for spending your time resolving this. THanks a lot :)

Comment: @Abhishek that's ok but that was the last shot of mine I guess hope that works and I can get my rep :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29435/discussion-between-abhishek-and-omer-faruk-almali)

Comment: @Abhishek I am waiting on the chat for 30 minutes, sorry I should go outside.

Comment: Opps I am sorry but I was waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work you can wrap it with 2 divs. Idea is to make any element inside these two divs behave like a table, td to be specific.

```
<div class="centerContainer">
   <div class="centerContent">
      <panel...>
      </panel>
   </div>
</div>

div.centerContainer
{ 
   top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
   position: absolute; display: table
}

div.centerContent {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle}
```

This works well with primefaces layout too !.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
   <!-- Header -->
   <!-- Footer -->

   <!-- Mid Content --> 
   <p:layoutUnit position="center">
      <div class="centerContainer">     
         <div class="centerContent">         
            <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
         </div>
      </div>            
   </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```